# How to handle an object in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, exception, error-handling

In the following code, every time I run program, the program stops and gives me a message to InputMismatchException. Of course this is a part of my program.

```
package listbasics;

import java.util.*;

 class AdjustStudents {

    private final ArrayList<Student> stu = new ArrayList<>();    // a Student ArrayList 

    public void addStudent(String name, double gpa) throws InputMismatchException {
        Student stu1 = new Student(name, gpa);
        stu.add(stu1);
    }
}
```

//--------- Two separate classes --------------

```
package listbasics;

import java.util.*;

    public class ArrayListBasics {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static AdjustStudents ad = new AdjustStudents();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addNewStudent();

    }

    public static void addNewStudent() {
        System.out.println("----- Adding A New Student -----");

        System.out.println(" Please enter student Name :");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" Please enter student GPA :");
        try {
            double gpa = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            ad.addStudent(name, gpa);
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Value !?");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I ran your code, and it didn't throw any `InputMismatchException`. what exactly is the problem you are facing? error on which line? what is the stack trace? what are you trying to achieve? what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the problem is you are expecting double but user is entering String so you can handle the situation like below.

`Scanner` has many hasNextXXX methods that can be used to validate input. Here's a brief about that:

for `Int` you can check like - `input.hasNextInt()`
for `Double` you can check like - `input.hasNextDouble()`

for your example -

```
public class ArrayListBasics {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static AdjustStudents ad = new AdjustStudents();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addNewStudent();

    }

    public static void addNewStudent() {
        System.out.println("----- Adding A New Student -----");

        System.out.println(" Please enter student Name :");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        double gpa = 0;
        System.out.println(" Please enter student GPA :");
        do {
            while (!input.hasNextDouble()){
                System.out.println(" Please enter valid GPA :");
                input.next();
            }
            gpa = input.nextDouble();
        }while (gpa  <= 0);
        ad.addStudent(name, gpa);
    }
}
```